# Создать таблицу 5x5 красных кружков, в которой 3 случайных кружка - желтого цвета. Pascal GraphABC

Tags: pascal, graph

**Вот что пока получается:**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Мой код:**

```
[![введите сюда описание изображения][2]][2]uses GraphABC;
var i,j:integer;

begin
  SetWindowSize(300,300);
  SetBrushColor(clRed);
  
  for i:=1 to 5 do
    for j:=1 to 5 do 
      circle(i*50,j*50,20)
      
end.
```

**Задание:** Сделать 3 случайных кружка желтым цветом.

Comment: Здесь не делают за Вас домашние задания.

Comment: Ну и в чем проблема? Генератор случайных чисел вам в помощь...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вроде работает:

```pascal
uses GraphABC;

var
  i, j: integer;
  brush, b_coun: integer;

begin
  SetWindowSize(300, 300);
  
  for i := 1 to 5 do
    for j := 1 to 5 do
    begin
      if(b_coun < 3) then begin
        brush := random(2);
        if(brush = 0) then SetBrushColor(clRed) else begin SetBrushColor(clGold); b_coun := b_coun + 1; end;
      end else SetBrushColor(clRed);
      circle(i * 50, j * 50, 20);
    end;
  
end.
```

Comment: Спасибо большое! Все работает